# Converting Hijri date to gregorian with jQuery Globalize

Tags: jquery-globalization

I am trying to convert a Hijri date back to Gregorian with the internal function in the ar-SA calendar (other calendars seem to have the same toGregorian function). For example code try:

```
Globalize.cultures["ar-SA"].calendars.standard.convert.toGregorian("1434", "03", "11");
```

According to sites I've seen like: http://www.islamicity.com/prayertimes/defaulthijriconv.asp

"1434", "03", "11" should be 1/23/2013.

However, each date seems to be off by 2 days and this function returns.. 1/21/2013..
Is there a problem with this function? Or some other issue I could be having by using it?

Or can someone propose a js function which would do the correct conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem it is because Month is zero based so the above code should be:

Globalize.cultures["ar-SA"].calendars.standard.convert.toGregorian("1434", "02", "11");

For todays date.